# How do I add an array to my JSON dictionary in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, post

I'm using swift in my ios app and I need help in creating the post request when an array is involved.

I need to post in the body of the http request something along the lines of this JSON:

```
{
    "someProperty1":"someValue1",
    "someProperty2":"someValue2",
    "someArray":[
        {"name":"nameValue1", "email":"emailValue1", "anotherProperty":"anotherValue1"},
        {"name":"nameValue2", "email":"emailValue2", "anotherProperty":"anotherValue2"},
        {"name":"nameValue2", "email":"emailValue2", "anotherProperty":"anotherValue2"},
    ]
}
```

I've been successful so far just creating a Dictionary for simpler requests that just looked like:

```
{"someProperty1":"someValue1",
"someProperty2":"someValue2"}
```

and then using

```
NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(requestBody, options: nil, error: &err)
```

where "requestBody" is a Dictionary

I have been unsuccessful in adding an array to this request can someone provide an example of how this might look? Thanks

Comment: I suggest you use SwiftyJSON for more simplify.

Comment: @Dato'MohammadNurdin I do have SwiftyJson in my project. It's great for parsing JSON I receive. I don't know how POST JSON is facilitated with swiftyJSON

Answer (score 2):

You can define your requestBody dictionary to contain `AnyObject` as a value, then add the array just like you would expect:

```
let arr: [String] = ["hi", "ho"]
let body: [String: AnyObject] = ["someProperty1":"someValue1", "someProperty2":"someValue2", "someProperty3":arr]

let json = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(body, options: nil, error: nil)
println(NSString(data: json!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can write this:

```
var paramArr = [["name":"nameValue1", "email":"emailValue1", "anotherProperty":"anotherValue1"], ["name":"nameValue2", "email":"emailValue2", "anotherProperty":"anotherValue2"],["name":"nameValue3", "email":"emailValue3", "anotherProperty":"anotherValue3"]]

var requestBody = [
    "someProperty1":"someValue1",
    "someProperty2":"someValue2",
    "someArray":paramArr]
```

---

By the way, The request param is too complex, I suggest you create data model to solve this problem.

the first model named `requestParam`,the second model named `user`. and rewrite set method to make `someArr` to `user` class (Sorry, I can use it in OC, but can't in Swift)

requestParam.swift

```
var someProperty1: String!
var someProperty2: String!
var someArray: NSArray!
```

user.swift

```
var name: String!
var email: String!
var anotherProperty: String!
```

then you can make all the param into requestBody model

then use some JSON library to dictionary

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use combination `Alamofire` and `SwiftyJSON`.

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import Haneke

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var datas: [JSON] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://xxxxx/ALL").responseJSON { (request, response, json, error) in
            if json != nil {
                if let data = jsonObj["someArray"].arrayValue as [JSON]?{
                    self.datas = data
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```